# How to open a minimized form in c#

Tags: c#

So right now I'm currently working on a bot for discord in c#. And I want to have a command were if I do that command and if my form is minimized. I want it to make the form pop up in it's default size. So basically I just want to know how to make a form appear in it's default size if it's minimized. Thx!

```
public void Bot_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Message.Text == "Command Here")
    {
        //Open the minimized form here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set your form's [**`WindowState` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Via this property you can control whether your form should be minimized, maximized, or of its normal size.